# Wiley publishes by print-on-demand -- publish by print-on-demand?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, terminology, countability, compounds

Example:

> Wiley publishes in a variety of print and electronic formats and **by print-on-demand**. Some material included with standard print versions of this book may not be included in e-books or **in print-on-demand**. If this book refers to media such as a CD or DVD that is not included in the version you purchased, you may download this material at http://booksupport.wiley.com. For more information about Wiley products, visit www.wiley.com.

There are actually two problems that I have with this excerpt. First, I don't understand how you can publish by print on demand. And second, in the phrase *in print on demand*, is *print on demand* being used as a mass noun?

Comment: In traditional publishing, a publisher would print some number of books, and hope that they'd all sell. _Print-by-demand_, on the other hand, is a model where publishers don't print the books until they are ordered; it leads to less waste. I don't work in that industry, but I'm guessing that advances in electronic storage and printing make print-by-demand a viable model (in the past, it would have been too time consuming to print books by demand rather than in batch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"By print-on-demand" in this example is an adverbial phrase.

Consider this example:

> His food processor was broken, so he had to chop the scallions **by hand.**

"By hand" in this case is the method he uses to perform the action of the verb.

The sentence you're asking about works just the same way.

There are different ways to print books. In the traditional publishing model, books are printed in bulk and unwanted ones are returned to the publisher or destroyed. This is what the writer means by "print...formats."

However, there are now new models, and this sentence describes two of them: you can publish **electronically,** where no physical book is printed at all, or you can print books **on demand**.

In the **publish-on-demand** model, a book is not printed until an individual customer requests ("demands") it. You then print and bind the book and mail it directly to the customer. "By print-on demand" in this case is an adverb phrase, because it explains how the action of the verb is performed, just like when you chop scallions "by hand."

You could rephrase the first sentence above like this:

> Wiley publishes books using different methods. Some books are printed using traditional print publishing methods. Some are printed only in electronic format. Some are printed using a print-on-demand method.

The second sentence is explaining that, when books are available in more than one format, those formats might have different contents. So if you order a book that was printed traditionally, it might come with a CD; if you order the same book, but in a print-on-demand edition, it might not have the CD. It's not a mass noun, because it's referring to a specific edition of an (unspecified) book.